# What do I have to change in my program to fix it from this annoying error code?

Tags: python

I have been trying to write a program that solves the following problem:

If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.

Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

To solve this I thought that I might write a function that makes a list of all the multiples of 3. I wanted it to take my list called "three", and multiply the last number by 3. And then add that number back into the list. It would then repeat until it reached 1000. (or in this case, 999)

When I try to run it the error message confuses me. What is wrong with the program?

```
three = [3, ]

def multiples_of_three():
    while (three != 999):
        high = (max(three))
        multiplied_three = (int(high *3))
        next_number_three = (multiplied_three, )
        three.append("next_number_three")

multiples_of_three()
print (three)
```

Here is the error message:

```
File "C:/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/World/My projects/Euler #1.py", line 
15, in <module>
    multiples_of_three()
  File "C:/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/World/My projects/Euler #1.py", line 
10, in multiples_of_three
    high = (max(three))
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: `three.append("next_number_three")` <= like "not do that"? You are appending the string `"next_number_three"`, not the value of the variable `next_number_three`.

Comment: Note that "three" will never equal 999. Three will only ever be this big list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative, and I think more readable, way of doing this:

```
def multiples_of_three():
    return [i for i in range(3, 1000, 3)] # a list of multiples of 3 from 1-1000

threes = multiples_of_three()
print (threes)
```

And further, we can make that function more general and use it to solve your example, here is how that may look:

```
def get_multiples(multiple, maximum):
    return [i for i in range(multiple, maximum, multiple)] # return all multiples in a list

def get_sum_of_multiples(multiples, maximums):
    all_multiples = set() # empty set
    for multiple, maximum in zip(multiples, maximums): # Iterate through the multiples and maximums
        current_multiples = get_multiples(multiple, maximum) 
        for num in current_multiples:
            all_multiples.add(num) # We add the multiples to a set because it will remove duplicates for us
    return sum(all_multiples) # return the sum of them all


multiples = [3, 5]
maximums = [1000, 1000]
print(get_sum_of_multiples(multiples, maximums))
```

Comment: Doesn't even need the list comprehension, just range(3, 1000, 3)

Comment: @CJPeine list comprehension or my entire answer?

Comment: It worked Thanks! The first answer!

Comment: @CJPeine I added some more to show you how you can use it more generally for your problem. Also, if this worked for you, please mark it as the accepted answer

Comment: do i do that by clicking the grey check mark? if so, i checked it.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes from around `"next_number_three"`.

Comment: you didn't test that did you?

Comment: I just did and i got:   File "C:/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/World/My projects/Euler #1.py", line 14, in <module>
    multiples_of_three()
  File "C:/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/World/My projects/Euler #1.py", line 9, in multiples_of_three
    high = (max(three))
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'

Comment: @CJPeine that was my point, there are more errors that other solutions have fixed

Answer (score 0):

Note, I know you probably need to write this as a homework assignment using specific techniques, but here is a more pythonic way:

```
multiples_of_three_or_five = [i for i in range(1,1000) if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0]
print sum(multiples_of_three_or_five)
```

Or you can be super fancy and just pen and paper math ;)

EDIT: Fancy math:

Summing integers from 1 to N results in N * (N+1)/2.

Summing the multiples of 3 below 1000 thus gives 3 * 332 * 333/2.

Summing multiples of 5 below 1000 gives 5 * 199 * 200 / 2

Now, just adding those two numbers gives the wrong answer, because you'd be double-counting those numbers that are multiples of both 3 *and* 5. But those are precisely the multiples of 15, so we subtract those. We check 1000/15 = 66.something, so 66*15 is still below 1000, so we subtract

15 * 66 * 67 / 2

and the final answer thus is 232169